# C# inheritance - same identifier on either side of ':'

Tags: c#, inheritance

I know `:` indicates inheritance in C#;

but what does it mean when the same identifier is on either side?

Eg

```
class GameObject : GameObject {
```

Comment: You should post an actual snippet of code. Your question as it is doesn't make sense.

Comment: You mean to say some thing like this?

class Derived : Base{}

Comment: it means a compiler error

Comment: Identical identifier = GameObject....

Answer (score 3):

It does not work, because Visual Studio will throw a 'cyclic dependency' error, because, when you think about it, GameObject inherits from GameObject which inherits from GameObject which inherits from... In other words, this is impossible, and so means nothing (except, like Neil mentioned in the comments, a compiler error).

Comment: ... which inherits from GameObject, which in turn inherits from GameObject, which is itself a GameObject, a GameObject that derives from a GameObject subclass called GameObject, that's also the parent class of GameObject, a GameObject subclass inherited from by GameObject whose superclass is GameObject...

Comment: @BoltClock - I was just editing my answer to include the endless ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Or this is Unicode

```
class GameObject
{

}
class GameObjеct : GameObject 
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you provided is legal if base class is declared in a different namespace
You need, however, use namespaces to resolve naming conflicts

Example

```
   namespace A
   {
       class GameObject
       {
       }
   }

   namespace B
   {

      class GameObject: A.GameObject
      {
      }
   }
```

Another possible scenario involves generics, which allow class name overload. The following will also compile:

```
class GameObject
{
}

class GameObject<T> : GameObject
{
}

class GameObject<T, T> : GameObject<T>
{
}
```

Comment: Technically both examples don't look like GameObject:GameObject.

Comment: You are right, technically it is not exactly same. I dont know what example the author had in mind, so I took my best guess.