# Why no Circular Inheritance with same base and derived class names

Tags: c#, inheritance

Just on [other thread at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116614/c-inheritance-same-identifier-on-either-side-of) today i found this small snippet code which i filled a bit more to make it complete,

```
class GameObject
{
    public virtual void Hello()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hello method in base class");
    }
}

class GameObjеct : GameObject 
{
    public override void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello method in derived class");

    }

}

class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameObject obj = new GameObject();//Why i never can call Derived? Though c# allows it?
        obj.Hello();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now as per the above code, the CSC shall not warning any thing at all. But the code works surprisingly.

I opened even the IL code using ILDasm, it shows the derived class i.e GameObject as 'GameObject' name and the base class name without ''.

So my question is

1. how the compiler is differentiating these both class names plus even at run time?
2. If pasted on notepad with ANSI encoding we get a weird char in the derviced class name as per my friend Abhishek sur. http://twitpic.com/68co6z

Thanks

EDIT: Update on the same code with different name, i am getting error from compiler.

```
class XXXYYY
    {
        public virtual void Hello()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello method in base class");
        }
    }

 class XXXYYY : XXXYYY
    {
        public override void Hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello method in derived class");

        }

    }

    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XXXYYY obj = new XXXYYY();//Why i never can call Derived? Though c# allows it?
            obj.Hello();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for adding my points too :)

Comment: Always will spread, respect and appreciate your help amigo. :)

Comment: I thought the strange syntax highlighting shown in [the answer you saw that code snippet in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116614/c-inheritance-same-identifier-on-either-side-of/7116720#7116720) made it obvious.

Comment: Score one for the SO syntax highlighter catching this.  Then file this in the *things you never do* category and move on to a real question.

Comment: Your edit is obviously using classes of the same names. Of course it won't compile.

Comment: I did the same before code as well (atleast as it looks if not edited properly by SO) or visiblity sake

Comment: @zenwalker: It's not clear what you mean by "I did the same before code as well".

Comment: Sorry wrong typo there. I actually meant i tried writing same name as before but not copy pasting it.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to give explanation?

Comment: @zenwalker: I didn't downvote, but it's likely coming from the fact that the discussions here don't seem to be making much headway; all of the answers posted point out that the character that looks like an `e` in your first code sample is not, in fact, an `e`. It's a different unicode character that simply *looks* like an `e`, and that's causing the confusion; you think they shouldn't compile because they look the same, but the compiler will compile them because they *aren't* the same. There's not significant about the fact that it's an `e` in particular, just that, in *this* case, it is.

Comment: Well adam, i agree with you only if you look at the overview. But please look at the whole answers and discussions and the updates i have done on the post. Theres alot of confusion and when tried with other names, the compilation varies. Hence this much discussion is going on. Or else i wouldnt care to flood SO. SOrry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically the character that looks like "e" in the second classname is a non-ASCII character. If you put that source code into a text file with an encoding which supports it (e.g. UTF-8) and tell the C# compiler what encoding to use (UTF-8 by default, I believe) then it will view them as different class names.

Ignoring the non-ASCII part, this is *really* just class:

```
public class Hello {}

public class He11o : Hello {}
```

In *some* fonts you can tell the difference between lower-case-ell and one, but in some you can't. They're different characters though.

When you tried to paste it into notepad it failed, because the ANSI encoding you're using (ANSI is an ambiguous term) doesn't include that character.

EDIT: Your second snippet doesn't compile for the obvious reason that you've got the same classname declared twice. Not two different names that look the same, but genuinely the *same name*.

Comment: So usage of UTF-8 is the issue here. Will there be any client machine where your forced to use ANSI when you do, this code always fails right. So why compiler designers allowed this in the first place though its not a mistake of their, but still to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Jon, I read an interesting article on Monday were a Hacker made the Hosts file hidden and created a new Hosts file were the "o" was a special char. Sneaky!

Comment: why on e char has to be? Why not some thing else? What if i use some ther word lets say XXYYY as class name?

Comment: @zenwalker the encoding on the client machine makes no difference.The point is the two classes are named differently and because of different names there's no ambiguity. The just look similar but even that won't be influenced by the client encoding since they are using the program not reading the source

Comment: See my EDIT on the same post please.

Comment: @zenwalker: No, it's not UTF-8. It's any character encoding which has one character which looks a bit like another. You may find that ANSI has a similar pair if you look hard enough. And no, it's not a language design failure either - the language just gives a perfectly reasonable set of Unicode characters as available in identifiers.

Comment: @zenwalker: Your edit tries to use the *actual same name* twice. I think you're missing the point of the original snippet - there are two different names. As far as the compiler is concerned, they're as different as ABC is to XYZ. You can't declare two classes with the same name, but you can declare two classes with names which happen to look the same in some fonts.

Comment: @Jon
I did the same with XXXYYY as i did with GameObject, i didnt copy and pasted. I wrote it by hand in VS actually.

Comment: @zenwalker: But did you make any attempt to make the two XXXYYY names different? If you just *typed* "GameObject" into Visual Studio, you'd end up with identical names too. What did you do to *try* to make the two names different?

Comment: @Jon,
For Gameobject, i copied the code from other thread which is in my first post. But the second one, i wrote it by hand. Sorry for late reply, i moved 2 home now.

Comment: @zenwalker: Right, so when you said you did it "as you did with GameObject", that's not actually true at all... in one case you copied and pasted from another page (where the name contained the non-ASCII character) whereas in the XXXYYY case you typed it in.

Comment: Well sorry for extending this a big time, but atleast for the visiblity sake, the VS editor should have outshowed the difference right. If some 1 see's the code, that person would surely bang head :) Hope it doesnt turn out in production code :)

Thanks every 1 for your help.

Comment: @zenwalker: This would only *ever* happen if someone was deliberately being obscure. I'd rather the Visual Studio team spent their time building features for normal scenarios rather than trying to prevent scurrilous developers doing evil weird stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken the e in the class GameObject thats inheriting GameObject is not ASCII e, but rather a special char e.

Comment: Reminds me of the [Naming section](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmainnaming.html) of [How to Write Unmaintainable Code](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmain.html) — see 'Accented Letters'.

Comment: So even if ILDasm doesnt show the actual different, then i  guess Microsoft itself has some issues here on their own tools.

Plus why on e char has to be? Why not some thing else? What if i use some ther word lets say XXYYY as class name?

Comment: @zenwalker I think there is some problem in Visual Studio IDE not detecting the special character. Notepad identifies it clearly.

Comment: Jethro, you're not mistaken. That's **exactly** what [the post in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116614/c-inheritance-same-identifier-on-either-side-of/7116720#7116720) said.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks i couldnt get that link before when posting this thread. Thanks for bringing it up. Ill update my post.

Comment: @zenwalker: Actually, I've added the link into your post already.

Answer (score 1):

My points are :

1 .

```
class GameObject
```

In IL it is GameObject

2 .

```
class GameObject:GameObject
```

In IL it is 'GameObject'

Both type differs in IL.

3 . In Visual Studio IDE, if you type the code, the e is not identified in GameObject. Hence there must be some ascii character present in the Source file that differs the two classes and when you copy and paste it shows that exactly.

That means your classes are different and as both Hello are virtual, the reference GameObject can call both base Hello and derived object depending on the object you pass.

Comment: i got that abhi, but my question is why only for "e" and not for any other names as i said my EDIT code.